# How to dockerize my play scala app?

Tags: scala, playframework, docker, h2

It is my first time using Docker. I installed it right and the daemon service is running, as say it is necessary. SO, I have a simple web app built with play Framework and scala language. After I run "sbt docker:publishLocal" I got "Built image play-scala-book:1.0-SNAPSHOT" success. I export "DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.0.8:2375". My built.sbt is >>

```
// import NativePackagerKeys._
// setting a maintainer which is used for all packaging types
maintainer := "Felipe Oliveira Gutierrez"
// exposing the play ports
dockerExposedPorts in Docker := Seq(9000, 9443)

name := """play-scala-book"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  evolutions,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.6",
  specs2 % Test
)
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
// enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

But when I run "docker run -p 9000:9000 play-scala-book:1.0-SNAPSHOT" I got this error >>

```
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:play
[error] o.j.StatementLogger - java.sql.Statement.executeQuery: select id, hash, apply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state like 'applying_%';
throws exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PLAY_EVOLUTIONS" not found; SQL statement:
select id, hash, apply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state like 'applying_%' [42102-191]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PLAY_EVOLUTIONS" not found; SQL statement:
select id, hash, apply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state like 'applying_%' [42102-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5349)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1245)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1884)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2032)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1878)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1699)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1687)
[warn] p.a.d.e.ApplicationEvolutions - Your production database [default] needs evolutions! 

# --- Rev:1,Ups - 96578d1
CREATE SEQUENCE book_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE book (
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('book_id_seq'),
label varchar(255),
added bigint
);

[warn] p.a.d.e.ApplicationEvolutions - Run with -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true if you want to run them automatically (be careful)
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - The application secret has not been set, and we are in prod mode. Your application is not secure.
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - To set the application secret, please read http://playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - The application secret has not been set, and we are in prod mode. Your application is not secure.
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - To set the application secret, please read http://playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - The application secret has not been set, and we are in prod mode. Your application is not secure.
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - To set the application secret, please read http://playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret
[info] application - ApplicationTimer demo: Starting application at 2016-05-29T15:57:43.182Z.
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - The application secret has not been set, and we are in prod mode. Your application is not secure.
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - To set the application secret, please read http://playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - The application secret has not been set, and we are in prod mode. Your application is not secure.
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - To set the application secret, please read http://playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - The application secret has not been set, and we are in prod mode. Your application is not secure.
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - To set the application secret, please read http://playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret
Oops, cannot start the server.
@708n7c3af: Database 'default' needs evolution!
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:75)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.withLock(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:99)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:49)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.start(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.<init>(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:150)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
    at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:47)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

On my conf/application.conf I have this >

```
play.evolutions {
  # You can disable evolutions for a specific datasource if necessary
  db.default.enabled = true
  db.default.autoApply = true
}
```

Comment: Do you want to solve de database error or the application secret error?

Comment: I think this is the major error to make me able to dockerize "cannot start the server. @708n7c3af: Database 'default' needs evolution!". But I already have evolutions on my libraries. I just want to dockerize my app

Comment: Maybe it can't find your application.conf file? Try to configure a good application secret in your application.conf. If this does not resolve the application secret issue and also the answer of Michael Vaughan does not work, likely you need to check whether your app can find application.conf.

Comment: hi, may I ask what's you base image

Comment: sorry, I deleted this project from my repository. maybe you can check this one (https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-akka) that is also in Scala and I created a docker image for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you don't have evolutions set to auto apply the ups. Try adding the line below to your `application.conf` and retry.

`play.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true`

Comment: Do you have a table named `play_evolutions` in your schema?

Comment: Yes, I edited the original question to show what is at my application.conf

Comment: Can you post the contents of `play_evolutions`?